# Net::SSH::Perl not working but up to date

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, cpan

I keep getting this when i try to run an SSH login

> Can't locate Net/SSH/Perl.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi
>   /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl
>   /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .)
>   at /scripts/test/ssh line 2. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   /scripts/test/ssh line 2.

but perl says its up to date

```
[root@SCRIPTS /]# cpanm Net::SSH::Perl
Net::SSH::Perl is up to date. (1.35)
[root@SCRIPTS /]#
```

the module says its up to date so im not sure where the issue is 
the script starts as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::SSH::Perl;
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: How did you install `Net::SSH::Perl`? If you used `cpanm`, there could have been permission issues and was installed somewhere below `~/`. If that's the case you will have to add this path to your `PERLLIB`

Comment: It doesn't look like ~/perl5/lib/perl5 is in the @INC. And as per chrsblck, that's probably where cpanm installed it too.

Comment: What's the output of `head -1 "$( which cpanm )"`?

Comment: Do you get the error message for `/usr/bin/perl -le'use Net::SSH::Perl; print $INC{"Net/SSH/Perl.pm"}'` run as root or do you get a path?

Comment: Try `perldoc -l Net::SSH::Perl` from the command line. This will either print out that the module can't be found or its location. From there, we can work out other possible issues.

Comment: The output is #!/usr/local/bin/perl  for  head -1 "$( which cpanm )"

Comment: [root@SCRIPTS]# perldoc -l Net::SSH::Perl   
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.17.4/Net/SSH/Perl.pm

Comment: @ikegami when i put in the command you have i get the error when i change the path to perl to /usr/local/bin/perl i get this back :  /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.17.4/Net/SSH/Perl.pm

Comment: So you have to installs of Perl. Where's the executable for the 5.17.4? `/usr/local/bin/perl`? (But why are you using a dev release? 5.odd is not for general use.)

Comment: I just uninstalled all perl and started again and it seems its easier to use Net:SSH2 anyway so thanks guys - i have something working that gets me what i want now.

Answer (score 3):

So `cpanm` is using a different perl. Maybe you have a `/usr/local/bin/perl` which cpanm uses.

Try `/usr/bin/perl -S cpanm` to install your modules for your system 5.8.8

The hint to try `perldoc -l Net::SSH::Perl` should also use `/usr/bin/perl -S perldoc -l Net::SSH::Perl` instead, as perldoc may also use a different perl.